# How can I create this design in HTML

Tags: css, html

[image]

I need to create a view like this to display comma separated tags being typed by the user. I am quite new to html so I only know how to do the basic highlighting.

```
<SPAN style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffff00">Example of highlighted text</SPAN>
```

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, an example is a list with border-radius

Comment: Look up `box-radius` and `margin`.

Comment: can you show the css and html you have so far so we can suggest additions

Comment: this is an unordered list, with a defined width and text-align: center. list-items are inline-block and a border-radius is applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```css
ul {
        width:200px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    li {
        display: inline-block;
        background: #A7B42D;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 1px 5px;
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:16px;
        font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks great, I will try it out and get back to accepting the answer

Comment: Quick question which one of the list item properties controls the spacing between the items I would like to increase this.

Comment: Never mind, margin it is.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use tools to make this because this request latest technologies in order to display propper round effects.
CSS3 PIE will do the trick easily, it can generate CSS rules to apply on elements:

http://css3pie.com/

With that site, you generate a CSS rule. then you have to apply this rule to multiple elements, so you can use what we call a "class". then the style that has the class will be applied in all items where you specified that class.

Example:

```
    .myClassDefinition
    {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffff00
    }

<p>normal text</p>
<p class="myClassDefinition"> text with myClassDefinition style</p>
```

For your request, Download PIE library on http://css3pie.com/download/, host it on your server, put it in "pie" folder and create that rule:

```
.greenRounded
{
border: 1px solid #696;
padding: 60px 0;
text-align: center; width: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
background: #EEFF99;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EEFF99), to(#66EE33));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

The latest line refers to the pie library that's hostes in your server, path relative to the current file that host the CSS rule! you cna change this!

Then with that CSS class, you want to apply this to all items you want, so make like that on items:

```
<span class="greenRounded">vase</span> <span class="greenRounded">flowers</span> <span class="greenRounded">china</span> <span class="greenRounded">orange</span>
```

Comment: I think he's looking for a complete answer, not just only the border-radius..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is using `ul` element with some CSS:

Take a look into this: http://jsfiddle.net/5agephjL/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>tag</li>
    <li>tag</li>
    <li>tag</li>
    <li>tag</li>
    <li>tag</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Of course your image shows complete example. You need to add specific colors, fonts, paddings, margins etc. But the skeleton is right.